# Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot to Desktop

Tags: icons, configure

The settings of extension desktop-icons@csoriano had an error:

```
SyntaxError: redeclaration of const ICON_SIZE
```

Stack trace:

```
_init@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/extensionsService.js:204:33
OpenExtensionPrefsAsync/<@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/extensionsService.js:122:28
asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:132:13
run@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/dbusService.js:175:20
main@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/main.js:19:13
run@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:222:19
start@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:206:5
@/usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Extensions:1:17
```

Comment: Could you put a bit more context around your question? When does the error show? Have you modified anything recently etc.

Comment: Thanks Nick I have resolved the issue already.